# doctrine 2.2 and codeigniter 2.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine-orm

I have searched a lot online for configuring the doctrine 2.2 and codeigniter 2.1, I could not find the appropriate tutorial for latest version of doctrine and codeigniter. Most of the tutorials are outdated. It would be greatly appreciated if have links for this tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can use https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/CodeIgniter-2-with-Doctrine-2  as the base, but really I prefer DataMapper over doctrine

Comment: thanks for links.... Its made me easy and no need configuration.... now it's working...... thanks a lot

Comment: sure! great job; made my day. If everybody's agree this [tool](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/tutorials/phpdoctrinemysql.jsp) is amazing for any codeigniter-doctrine fan.