# How to dump mysql table schema into yaml format

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4

What is the quickest way create yaml file from mysql database table schema?

So, I have a mysql database structure already created. I want to dump it in yaml format a put it into "config/doctrine/schema.yaml" and after that i want to run "php symfony doctrine:build-schema" (symfony 1.4).

I am missing part where i need to dump table structure into yaml format. What is the quickest way to do it?

Thanks for any help

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108297/doctrine-2-2-and-codeigniter-2-1/9150070#comment14724164_9150070) save me light-years of work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the [Doctrine CLI](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/cookbook/1_0/en/code-igniter-and-doctrine%3asetup-command-line-interface). The generate-yaml-db option lets you...

> Generate a YAML schema file from an existing database

Comment: The link you posted is for documentation of Doctrine Sandbox which is not available to download anymore on their website. Can you advice how/where to download doctrine cli?

Comment: I found a solution. Actually "php symfony doctrine:build-schema" will generate yaml file for me in "config/doctrine/schema.yml"